# Node.js coding assistance is disabled and cannot be turned on [IntelliJ 2019.3]

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

Coding assistance doesn't turn on, even if node js related stuff is recognized. I've also tried node v12 but same sad story.

If I check the "Coding assistance for Node.js", it lets me select the module but then it un-checks itself.

I've already tried other solutions found in some similar (but old) topics, but none of them worked.

[image: node js settings intellij]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows 10. When I downgraded NodeJS to node-v11.15.0-x64, I was able to check the box without it unchecking itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> If I check the "Coding assistance for Node.js", it lets me select the
> module but then it un-checks itself.

You can try this (it works for me, I am using nodejs 13.14.0):

1. Close PHPstorm
2. You need in the .idea folder to create a jsLibraryMappings.xml file with the next content:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project version="4">
      <component name="JavaScriptLibraryMappings">
        <includedPredefinedLibrary name="Node.js Core" />
      </component>
    </project>
   ```
3. Find the line with the following component in the workspace.xml file:

   ```
    <component name = "PropertiesComponent">
   ```
4. Add the following property for this component (You may need to specify the version of your node):

   ```
    <property name="javascript.nodejs.core.library.configured.version" value="13.14.0" />
   ```

*Sorry, I am using a translator*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out I did not [activate the NodeJS plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxYE3.png).